# Mathematica hangs on opening at start up on Mac OS X 10.11 (Yosemite)

Tags: warning-messages

Since updating to Mac OS X 10.11 (Yosemite), Mathematica 10.0 will not start.  I just get the spinning beachball, with no error messages, but it does not crash.  I've tried suggested fixes (Deleting Library/Mathematica/Paclet, and re-installing Java SE 6) but nothing has helped.  There is no error code and the console log is not helpful (to me).

I would try updating Mathematica to 10.3, but the dmg file from Wolfram won't open! It is not recognized.

Any suggestions? Any ideas of how to see where things are failing?

Answer (score 2):

Updating to 10.3 worked out.  I had to redownload the file - it was somehow corrupted.  Still, I don't know why it was a fix.